# Using Images as Input to a Bidirectional LSTM Network

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I want to know how to process images before being fed as an input to a Bidirectional LSTM. I always get this error whenever I run me code:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

from this line:

```
outputs, _, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Here's a part of my code relevant to the problem:

```
def bi_rnn(features, labels, mode):
    x = tf.unstack(features, num_inputs, 1)
    ... # cell initialization
    # Get lstm cell output
    try:
        outputs, _, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

... 

def serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = {
        'features': tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_inputs])
    }
    features = {
        key: tf.expand_dims(tensor, -1) for key, tensor in feature_placeholders.items()
    }
    features = tf.squeeze(features, axis=[2])
    return InputFnOps(features, None, feature_placeholders)

def read_dataset(img_paths, labels):
    def _input_fn():
        ... # reading image paths omitted
        image_files = tf.image.decode_png(image_files)
        image_files = tf.image.resize_images(image_files, [1024, 128])
        image_files = evaluate_images(image_files)
        ... # labels part omitted
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(image_files)), labels2
    return _input_fn
```

Comment: I can't trace the exact error using the provided code and error (having a full stack trace is generally more useful than just an error), but my guess would be that you are passing a python list where the method expects a Tensor.

Comment: Here's the gist containing the code and the stacktrace

https://gist.github.com/selcouthlyBlue/ee06c170ea22ee82695a219e871f9c2c

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but the doc for bidirectional_dynamic_rnn requires `inputs` (`x` in your case) to be a Tensor or a tuple of Tensors. In the code from the gist, it is a list (as returned by `tf.unstack`). I am not sure why you even need the call to `tf.unstack` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pretty much gave up on this one already and made [something else](https://github.com/selcouthlyBlue/bi_lstm_ocr) work. It doesn't use the TFLearn features unlike this one. The recent one I'm working on has a problem which you can view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577833/using-bi-lstm-ctc-tensorflow-model-in-android).